# How to loop an MPEG TS stream

Tags: android, ffmpeg, stream, mpeg, mpeg2-ts

I'm looking for a way to stream a TS file as an infinitely looping http stream. I've tried just concatenating the file but that results in playback corruption.

I have basic code to read the TS packet headers, but I'm not sure how packets relate to the underlying video stream. Are frames aligned to packets (so potentially I can loop it by repeating the right packets) or would I have to fully demux/remux the original TS stream for it to work?

The service that will hosting the http stream will be running on one of those Amlogic S802 based Android STBs, is it possible to pipe this data through the Android version of ffmpeg through Java or would any solution have to be purely Java?

Answer (score 2):

TS files contain timestamps (PTS and DTS) and some player do depend on them, some do not.

For example, if you take `.ts` files from an HLS stream and concatenate them, they usually play normally, because timestamps are continuous in the chunks.

In your case you may try to use concatenate format or filter in ffmpeg - https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Concatenate

You could also manually parse TS packets, but I'd recommend to use `libav` library's demuxer for that to extract video and audio packets.

If you are running on Android, then you can take a look at Google's open source player implementation of `TsExtractor` - https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer/blob/master/library/src/main/java/com/google/android/exoplayer/hls/parser/TsExtractor.java

Comment: I've spent some time playing with ffmpeg generated HLS sequences but unfortunately they won't loop, instead near the end of the sequence the video stalls for around 1 sec before it's supposed to finish then starts at the beginning of the sequence. On the very last loop of the sequence (I'm only looping several times for now) it plays right through to the end. I've tried both concatenating the separate ts files generated by ffmpeg as well as editing the m3u8 to include the same files several times.

Comment: if it stops, make sure that you put `#EXT-X-ENDLIST` in the end, otherwise the player will be expecting more data

Comment: It's not that, when I have

    #EXTM3U
    #EXT-X-VERSION:3
    #EXT-X-TARGETDURATION:3
    #EXT-X-MEDIA-SEQUENCE:8
    out0.ts
    out1.ts
    out2.ts
    out0.ts
    out1.ts
    out2.ts
    out0.ts
    out1.ts
    out2.ts
    #EXT-X-ENDLIST

It always stalls between out2.ts and out0.ts

Comment: oh I see, I didn't realise that you putting `.ts` files in the loop in HLS. Then try to put `#EXT-X-DISCONTINUITY` before `out0.ts` - https://tools.ietf.org/html/draft-pantos-http-live-streaming-14#section-4.3.2.3